# Time picker android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to android development and I want to add a `time picker` to my code. I followed same tutorial but when I use the emulator it doesn't work. Even `genymotion` tells me there is a problem in the execution of my app (and there is not a bug in my code) the error began when I put `showTimePickerDialog()` in  `onCreate()`. This is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    Button button_stpd;
    static final int DIALOG_ID = 0 ;
    int hour_x;
    int minute_x ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         showTimePickerDialog();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Acceuil, new Acceuil()).commit();

            showTimePickerDialog();
    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(){
        button_stpd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.temps_btn);
        button_stpd.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id){
        if (id == DIALOG_ID)
            return new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, kTimePickerListner,hour_x,minute_x,false);
        return null;
    }

    protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener kTimePickerListner =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    hour_x = hourOfDay;
                    minute_x = minute;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,hour_x + ":"+minute_x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager() ;



        if (id == R.id.nav_Acceuil) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Acceuil, new Acceuil()).commit() ;
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Messagerie) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Acceuil, new Messagerie()).commit() ;


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Notification){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Acceuil, new Notification()).commit() ;


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Paramétres) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Acceuil, new Parametre()).commit() ;

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_Calories) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Acceuil, new Calcule()).commit() ;

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue ?

Comment: 1. what is the error. Does logcat says something. If not, what exactly is happening?
2. Please indent your code :)
3. Why do you have 2 times this showTimePickerDialog()?

Comment: Off-topic: showDialog/onCreateDialog/onPrepareDialog has been deprecated for years. Since Android 3 and fragments - in this case DialogFragment - came out to be precise.

Comment: the issue is that i want to add a TimePicker in my project and when i do like the tutorials i don't work in my project but it work in another blank activity

Answer (score 0):

```
  button_stpd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.temps_btn);
    button_stpd.setOnClickListener(...
```

This code is linking the Button you have in Java code to the Button you have in your xml layout. Such code should be only written once and as it is part of your
showTimePickerDialog() method which you use twice, that's a big problem.

If you want to do initiation in another method so that onCreate looks clean, that's fine, but use that method only once. It could be called initiateViews() for example and you could do such things inside it as:

```
 button_stpd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.temps_btn);
 button_stpd.setOnClickListener(... 
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

However, from what I understand, the second time you are using `showTimePickerDialog()`, what you really wanted was  `showDialog(DIALOG_ID);`